# Regarding installation of Cygwin in Windows 8.1

Tags: cygwin

How to download the cygwin, as I am not getting the list of mirror sites while running the set up file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not obtaining the mirror list, there is likely a Proxy in the middle. 
Check Proxy settings

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-connection